# Changing state value doesn't work properly on react-table

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I am trying to add a "delete" button to every row of data using react-table. Button splices the data and removes that line from data when pressed. When the "delete" button is clicked for the first time it works properly. However on the second press nothing happens. For some reason `changeData` doesn't change the data on the second run. Why this happens?

```
function DataTable({columns, data_rows}) {
    const [data, changeData] = useState(data_rows);

    if (columns[0].Header !== "Action") {
        columns.unshift({
            Header: 'Action'
        });
    }
    columns[0]['columns'] = [{
        Header: ' ', Cell: ({row}) => (
            <ButtonGroup>
                <Button className="button-dark button-sm" onClick={() => {
                    const dataCopy = [...data];
                    dataCopy.splice(row.index, 1);
                    changeData(dataCopy);}}>
                    Remove
                </Button>
            </ButtonGroup>
        )
    }]
    const {
        getTableProps,
        getTableBodyProps,
        headerGroups,
        rows,
        prepareRow
    } = useTable({
        columns,
        data
    });


    return (
        <table {...getTableProps()}>
            <thead>
            {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
                <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
                    {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
                        <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>{column.render("Header")}</th>
                    ))}
                </tr>
            ))}
            </thead>
            <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
            {rows.map((row, i) => {
                prepareRow(row);
                return (
                    <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                        {row.cells.map(cell => {
                            return <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render("Cell")}</td>;
                        })}
                    </tr>
                );
            })}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    );
}
```

Comment: have you try something like `changeData(preVal => preVal.splice(row.index, 1) )` in your onClick?

Comment: @antoineso Yup. Same result sadly.

Comment: Update: managed to solve it by slightly modifying @antoineso's comment. I copied an array from previous state and spliced it:
`changeData((preVal) => { const dataCopy = [...preVal]; dataCopy.splice(row.index, 1); return dataCopy; });`

Comment: Where is row.index coming from inside the onclick?